# Converting DayOfYear values in Javascript for use in Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, plot, flot

I'm trying to get a usable display from the flot jQuery library by having the X Axis display dates; however, the data I'm receiving is in DayOfYear format, instead:

```
var data = [[192,6.9],[191,49.52],[190,2],[189,0], etc...]
```

192, 191, etc represent days of the year, and I would like to convert them to actual dates. I'd appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getDate(iYear, iDayOfYear) {
    var oDate = new Date(iYear, 0);
    oDate.setDate(iDayOfYear);
    return oDate;
}
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/qt6Yr/).

Comment: what's the difference to my solution?

Comment: @christoph - your solution creates two new Date objects; scessor's only creates one.  Other than that, they're identical.